# no numbering for table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

i don't want numbering on table of contents page in beamer but i want it to be bulleted. I am using Berkeley theme

how to do this?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack: don't remove the number, but make it invisible

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{fg=}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To use arbitrary shapes instead of the rectangles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.75ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{section number projected}%
    \textbullet% or whatever
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{\hfil\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber\hfil}}%
  \kern1.25ex\inserttocsection\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks - it worked - but still can we change bullets - just being curious

Comment: @pva18 See my edit

Comment: that does not work for the bullets in Boadilla, as they have light effect, so setting the color is not making them disappear